# Is there a way to manually set a function address?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I want to make a global or static function, but to be sure that the function address takes 24 bits max. Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: I am using arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc cross compiler for arm architecture. Main program is statically linked and translated in arm mode. What I actually want is to relocate printf symbol, but &printf takes 4B,so instruction BL &printf won't do. So, I can have 3B max.

Comment: That's a strange requirement. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Function address always take the constant size (in compiled file) of `sizeof(void*), usually 32 or 64 bits.

Comment: On Posix, function pointers are the same size as object pointers (one word); see `dlsym`...

Comment: @Andrey: "always"? Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @Andrey No, not always, it's not required. (Oh, you're a C# developer, I see.)

Comment: How otherwise it will fit into pointer variables?

Comment: @Andrey It doesn't. Outside of POSIX, function pointers don't need to fit into data pointers.

Comment: @H2CO3 that is something new for me. How is getting function address and assigning it is supposed to work?

Comment: @Andrey Like this: `void (*fptr)() = &some_function;`

Comment: @H2CO3 and you say that later may not work: `void* p = fptr;` ?

Comment: @Andrey Yes, exactly.

Comment: just to answer the first question - I have some bl instruction which is 4B long,and the first byte is for opcode, so i'm left with 3B for address.

Comment: @Andrey: C 2011 6.3.2.3 paragraph 1 says “A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type…” Paragraph 8 says “A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again;…” The standard does not contain provision for converting pointers to functions to pointers to object types (including void) or vice-versa.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks for pointing to reference, now I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this in standard C. You must use features particular to your developer tools and your target platform. You have not stated what those are, so we cannot give you specific advice.

Most architectures provide for a branch with an offset from the current instruction, in which case your requirement would be that the destination function is near the call, not that it is within the first 2<sup>24</sup> bytes of the address space. Are you sure you have a branch instruction that branches to an absolute address and that contains a 24-bit immediate value?

The assembler and the linker may have methods by which the location of a program section can be set, and you may be able to place the target function into a particular section and then set the address of that section. Doing so improperly may violate rules in your target operating system, so you need to understand the layout of executable programs in your target system.

Often, the default behavior of the linker will result in suitable addresses for your code, unless your program is large. If the target address is too large for the immediate field of the instruction, the linker should produce an error. This means there is, at least, no danger that your program will execute incorrectly, since the error will be detected before building is complete.

You might consider alternatives such as a sequence of several instructions that builds a complete address (so that it can handle an address of any size) and branches to the complete address. There are usually instructions to assist with this, such as instructions to load the high part of a value, add the low part, and jump to the address stored in a register.

Comment: can you help me with these instructions? it's arm architecture.

Comment: @MarsaPalas: First, write this C code: `#include <stdio.h`, `void foo(void) { printf(""); }` and compile it with your usual switches with `-S` added (and `-o` and `-c` omitted if you were using those). That tells GCC to produce assembly code, instead of object code. Then you can look at the instructions GCC uses to generate calls to other functions. You can probably use that code. If that does not work, you could ask another Stack Overflow question, “How do I write ARM assembly to branch to a location too far for the BL immediate instruction?” Include the GCC and specific ARM version.

Comment: @MarsaPalas: ARM has `movw` and `movt` instructions that load the bottom and top halves of a register, to form a full 32-bit address, so you may be able to do something like `movw r0, :lower16:_printf`, `movt r0, :upper16:_printf`, `blx r0`. However, that is Apple GCC syntax, and the details about loading relocatable symbols depend on the target platform, so you may need something more involved. That is why compiling with your compiler is a good way to get the details for your target platform.

Comment: Also, as I wrote, it is a bit odd that you cannot branch simply with `BL`. You may be writing something wrong. E.g., perhaps you tried `printf` instead of `_printf` and got a link error and concluded the reason was the limit of the immediate value rather than using the wrong name? What is the specific error you get? What is the specific line of assembly you wrote?

Comment: Thank you!Your answer is mostly appriciated,so I'll mark it. These instructions are just like for an arm architecture.

Comment: I still haven't tried this, because I'm running out of time for my project(I left BL offset, and said there is an error if offset runs out), but I'm wondering..well,I would have to insert 8B inside .text section. Will that mess things up?All addresses will go down 8B...

Comment: I was looking again for the solution and I came here (page 117) http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/DUI0204J_rvct_assembler_guide.pdf I've searched what this documnt recomended http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0285b/DUI0285B_rvdk_linker_guide.pdf but honestly, I don't understand those veneers..I need a vacation :(

Answer (score 1):

I guess, yes you can set the function address manually in the embedded C programming at least. For this you have to edit the linker file where you can specify the address of an object ( or function). Use this address in your code using compiler  directives  called "#pragma".

Comment: my question does have to do with linkers. You see, I want to do relocation of function call, but that function shouldn't be far away from where I'm jumping with instruction bl funcAddress (it's arm assembler,btw),so I need somehow to solve that mabue with a wrapper function,that will be set somewhere closer.

Comment: @MarsaPalas You can't do that other than with a linker script. The linker will ultimately determine where the functions go in memory, so it is the linker you need to control - you can't control that at the C or compiler level.

Comment: OK,then I will make linker script and I will say where mu .text section will go. But,how can I know my .text section isn't long enough that my function address goes wrong again? Is there some order that I can be sure which function goes before the other? I mean, If I first define f() function,and after that f1() function, will f appear on the lower address than f1?

Answer (score 0):

You just want your function to be loaded at the lowest possible address. Why don't your define the function at the top of the file and compile that into ".o" file. Give this file as 1st file to the loader. Make your main() as simple and small one.

This is just my guess. This may put your function at lowest possible address.

Comment: that may be good. offourse, I will also have to use linker scripts as nos said, but there are also other things I'm not still sure as I've mentioned in one of my posts.